# Filters used in FBMC

Tags: digital-communications

On page 137, chapter 5 in the book titled *5G Physical Layer: Principles, Models and Technology*, the author says:

> An important attribute of the FBMC waveforms is that they typically do
> not employ any CP or GI, unlike the OFDM-based waveforms. The
> prototype filters in the FBMC waveforms have long decaying tails which
> can make them robust to the ISI caused by frequency-selective channels

Question: Why would filter long decaying tails make a signal robust to ISI caused by frequency selectivity?

Answer (score 1):

> > long decaying tails which can make them robust
>
> Why would filter long decaying tails make a signal robust

*can* make them robust, not *makes* them robust!

You need a long filter length for narrow bandwidth and steep transition width.

So, with a long filter, you can make very narrow subcarrier channels.

Those being narrow, they don't "see" multipath, they only see a flat channel.

Comment: is the "ISI caused by frequency-selective channels" interference between *subcarriers* ?

Comment: no, that'd be ICI. ISI happens between consecutive symbols on the same subcarrier.

Comment: but flat fading is also what each subcarrier sees in OFDM as well, so what is the difference?

Comment: That one is OFDM and the other is FBMC. You're reading a book on it! OFDM has a rectangular window shape, and doesn't have a long-tailed filter, exactly as it says in the text you're quoting.

Comment: You said that flat fading is the reason of not seeing multipath in FBMC , but flat fading applies also to OFDM for each  subcarrier. Your argument is about flat fading

Comment: yes, in each carrier of FBMC. You realize what the abbreviation stands for, don't you?

Comment: I prefer to end this discussion with no further comments